# How to unlink the teaser title from the original content?

Tags: views, entities, nodes

I have a page having list of teasers populated using views for a certain content type. Now, I want the title of the teaser not to be a link to the original content/node. I want the title in same format but not to be a link. Please help if anybody know how to do it.
I am using Drupal 7.

Answer (score 1):

On the view you are using, simply click  on the title field, and uncheck link field to original piece of content

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer @4life. But my view is not using any field. It is a teaser of content.

Answer (score 1):

You can make it by override the node.tpl
just go node.tpl.php in your theme and change this lines

```
<?php if (!$page): ?>
    <h2<?php print $title_attributes; ?>>
      <a href="<?php print $node_url; ?>"><?php print $title; ?></a>
    </h2>
  <?php endif; ?>
```

To be

```
<?php if (!$page): ?>
    <h2<?php print $title_attributes; ?>>
     <?php print $title; ?>
    </h2>
  <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I think this code will change apply to every node. I want this option only for a particular content type.

Comment: you can override just one node using node--[content type].tpl.php example node--page.tpl.php or use if condition if(node->type=="page"){}else{}